# PHP Laravel route any - best way to serve ReactJS application without asset conflict when relogging?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code in Laravel that serves a React application that manipulates history states (reactRouter):

```
Route::any('{any}', 'HomeController@reactLoader')->where('any', '.*');
```

In Laravel, how to make Route::any accept all uri's except ones containing a dot? I want to prevent Laravel remembering invalid asset routes (ex: .map file) and serving it when a user relogs into the app.

I have tried with the following regex expression (didn't work): ^[^.]*$
Successful assets are served directly using Nginx, which they don't hit Laravel router hence not a problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "remembering?" Laravel redirects to whatever page was originally requested after login.

Comment: Yes but when invalid href are triggered, Laravel serves back the ReactJS application and serves that page when logging back in. That is why I want to restrict dot in the Route::any statement to make it a normal 404 error page which Laravel won't redirect when logging back in.